google_sign_in desktop in flutter, error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
I'm working on a google signin/login button. It works well on website(chrome) and android. But when I tried it on the desktop(window), I had a problem
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)
Although the error is the same as this question, I haven't found any solution

As the documentation says google_sign_in
This package does not support Windows or Linux at the moment
Check your application requirements and
If it's really necessary for it to work on Windows, I suggest looking at some alternatives like this firebase_auth

According to documentation.
Linux,windows not supported
docs
